# CSS: Image only showing half height, and showing multiple times width wise?

Tags: html, css

It seems that my code is repeating the image width ways, and only showing half of it height wise?

```css
    html, body {
        background-color: black;
    }
    
    .tile.floor {
        background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/7es7QMs.png');
    }
    
    .tile.floor:empty::after {
        content: "\200b";
        visibility: hidden;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="tile floor"></div>
    <script src="/assets/js/app.js"></script>
```

I have attached a JS fiddle with all the code I'm using.

[JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wo2L8cku/)

Comment: `background-size: auto 100%;` ?

Comment: This isn't what I'm looking for. Test it out on  the JS fiddle and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: **background-repeat: no-repeat;** - that’s for repeating the image

Comment: I already tested, and applying my code you will fix the *half height* issue. If it's not what you want edit to be more precise

Comment: You don't fix my issue. It fixes the half height issue by halfing the size of the image, making it pixelated. Thanks for the attempt, but it isn't want I'm looking for, as I stated in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `.tile.floor`'s height to the height of the image.

```
html, body {
    background-color: black;
}

.tile.floor {
    background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/7es7QMs.png');
    height: 40px;
}

.tile.floor:empty::after {
    content: "\200b";
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

As per my understanding, it does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking for here. But if you want the image to resize to the height of your element, use `background-size: contain`.

```
.tile.floor {

    background: url('https://i.imgur.com/7es7QMs.png') no-repeat; /* Remove no-repeat if you want it to tile */
    height: 38px; /* Whatever height you want */
    background-size: contain;
}
```